# How to iterate multiple sequences or collections of the items in one single #list?

Tags: freemarker

I have two collections of the items and I want to iterate over one single `<#list>`.

I tried as follows but it gives me an error:

```
<#list [tags, categories] as entry>
    <p>${entry.category}</p>
    <p>${entry.tag}</p>
</#list>
```

> Expected hash. entry evaluated instead to
>   freemarker.template.SimpleSequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a somewhat unusual data structure, but as far as something assures that the two lists has equal length, you could do this:

```
<#list categories as category>
  <p>${category}</p>
  <p>${tags[category?index]}</p>
</#list>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But if I have a method how can I call it? I tried `${tags[category_index.getName()]}`

Comment: Yes, the index is only available in the scope of the loop variable (which is a lexical scope). Note sure what the method does, but certainly you have to pass in the index itself (`category?index`).